# How to query a limit of employees under all companies?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Suppose I have a list of companies. Some companies employ employees. 
I want to query all companies together with a limit of 3 employees from each company, as well as a total number of employees employed by each company.

Right now my query looks like this:

```
MATCH (c:Company) 
    OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:EMPLOYS]->(p:Person)
    WITH c, p
    LIMIT 3
    RETURN c, p, count(p) as total
    ORDER by c.name;
```

But I am getting only 1 employee under each company.

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant but it should get what you want. Returns all Company nodes, three Person nodes and the total of Person nodes connected to the Company Node

```
MATCH (c:Company)-[:EMPLOYS]->(p:Person)
WITH c, collect(p) as people
RETURN c, people[0..3], size(people) as total
ORDER by c.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns up to 3 employees (even when there are none)

```
MATCH (c:Company)
WITH c,
     [(c)-[:EMPLOYS]->(p:Person)| p] AS persons
RETURN c, persons[0..3], size(persons) as total
ORDER by c.name
```